# What happens after editing an on-hold question?

Tags: discussion, editing

I made some edits to [this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/126577/what-are-the-disadvantages-to-deferring-animation) in attempt to make it less opinion seeking. They edits were approved, but I'm curious as to what happens next. Do the on-hold / close voters get automatic notice of the edits? Should I flag it for moderator attention?

Note: I'm not necessarily advocating for said question or my edits - it might still not be a good enough fit for the site.

Comment: FWIW I don't think your edits, while sound, address the fundamental issue with the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Questions that are edited after being put on hold or closed will appear in the "Reopen" review queue for users with sufficient reputation.